# Extract field value

Tags: c#, regex

How to extract **User-Name value** from strings below with Regex:

> Acc sfjlsf56 1 0 User-Name=User_1, Group-Name=DCN_VPN_Support,

must be User_1

> Acc t3we89ab 1 0 User-Name=John,Group-Name=DCN_VPN_Support,

must be John

> Acc y5g769bo 1 0 User-Name=,Group-Name=DCN_VPN_Support,

must be null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the username, we look for the `User-Name=` token, then match all characters after it that aren't a `,` (which denotes the next element). We tag this matched group with the name `"username"` to retrieved it later:

`User-Name=(?<username>[^,]*)`

```
var match = Regex.Match(stringToMatch, "User-Name=(?<username>[^,]*)");
string username = match.Success ? match.Groups["username"].Value : null;
```

Note that this will match the empty user as `""` (`String.Empty`) rather than `null`. If `null` is required, simply translate it afterwards.

Comment: Nop, realized now my mistake :P +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the User-Name=[a-z\d]*, you can use